# How to I configure my .travis.yml file to run the script for building image which is already included as a .sh file in the repositiry

Tags: bash, docker, travis-ci, devops

I am trying to configure Travis-CI for my private repo.

```
sudo: required

services:
  - docker

script:
  - bash ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh
```

Here, `ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh` is the file which I want to run to build images every time a change is triggered in the repository.

Here is the log of the Travis-CI:

```
Starting instance
✓ selected image "travis-ci-connie-trusty-1512502258-986baf0"
✓ rendered startup script
✓ inserted instance
• sleeping 15s before checking instance insert
• polling for instance insert completion...
✓ instance is ready (16.695s)
step_upload_script
...
...

0.00s$ bash ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh
bash: ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh: No such file or directory
The command "bash ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh" exited with 127.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like `ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh` can't be found. Is it accessible from the working directory at that path? Could you run `ls -l ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh` before executing it to check if the script exists? Run also `pwd` to check your working directory.

Comment: The file path after uploading it to github repositoiry is 
`ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that we need to convert each absolute path into a relative path by using the system variable $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR.

So all I needed to do was to add this variable before the file path.

Example:

```
{TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR}/ca-k8s-images/images/endor/buildimages.sh
```